# Determining if HTML Button is Disabled in IE

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm doing some VBA recently for work and I need to check in a webpage to click a button if is enable and don't click if is disabled.

BUT! I don't know how to make VBA check the disabled button.

Here is the button code:

```htm
<input name="formAction:proxima" title=">" disabled="disabled" class="button" id="FormAction:proxima" type="submite" value=">">
```

I tried some If, but didn't work

```
    Set nxt = IE.document.getElementById("formAction:proxima")

    If nxt Is Nothing Then
        IE.Quit
    Else
        nxt.Click
    End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the `.disabled` property *(Boolean)*.

```
Dim nxt As HTMLButtonElement
Set nxt = IE.document.getElementById("formAction:proxima")

If nxt.disabled Then
    ie.Quit
Else
    nxt.Click
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the button `disabled` property. Try this:

```
Set nxt = IE.document.getElementById("formAction:proxima")

If nxt.getAttribute("disabled") = "disabled" Then
     IE.Quit
Else
     nxt.Click
End If
```