# VBA Loop untill "disabled" is in the name

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, foreach

I got the code below working, but as you can see it takes a lot of time. Because  I need to be sure that all the results are loaded. I think I am looking for a loop instead?

```
Sub LaadAllePaginaenScrape()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    'Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim e As Integer

e = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = False

URL = "Somepage"

ie.navigate URL

Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

Do While ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")
botao.Click (1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

For Each htmlEle In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
        .Range("B" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
        .Range("C" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
    End With

    e = e + 1
Next htmlEle

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The following code is been used in the VBA code to click on the specific button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding" 
     ng-disabled="!lastCallHadData" ng-click="addPage()" 
     data-ajaxform-clicked="">
    <span ng-show="loading" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning ng-hide"></span> 
       Laad meer resultaten
</button>
```

But I want to loop untill the code has a disabled attribute(?) in the tag.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding" 
     ng-disabled="!lastCallHadData" ng-click="addPage()" 
     data-ajaxform-clicked="" disabled="disabled"> << Here you have the attribute disabled
      <span ng-show="loading" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning ng-hide"></span> 
           Meer resultaten niet gevonden
 </button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330011/determining-if-html-button-is-disabled-in-ie/49330249

Comment: Thanks, but both solutions didn't work. Some 438 error when useing the getElementById and 13 error when using the original GetElementByClassName.Dim nxt As HTMLButtonElement
Set nxt = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")

If nxt.disabled Then
    ie.Quit
Else
    nxt.Click
End If

Comment: Your button has no id attribute, so not sure why you'd use getElementById ?  I only pointed to that question as an example of how to access the disabled attribute.  Did you try accessing `botao.getAttribute("disabled")` ?

Comment: If you use *botao.getAttribute("disabled")* that attribute must be there. In the html snipets I can see this attribute only in the second example wich should be the last button. If an attribute you ask for is missing you get a runtime error. So you must use *botao.hasAttribute("disabled")* I think.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I have no idea why I used the getElementById, perhaps it was some kind of logic to me. I do not have the knowledge and experience to know this. If it comes to prograrmmering which I have to do from time to time it is just copy and paste it with a lot of trial and error. I tried to learn programming, but somehow I don't get it, the language barriere I guess. On topic: At the moment I have a better solution via Power Query, which gives me the data in a table for each row(the data when you click on it) The url: https://sportvloeren.sport.nl/sportvloerenlijst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many little errors in your code and I can't say any more without html code. If there are more problems it would be the best you post the url. You can try this:

Edited: Reorder macro code [loop borders, get data, button click and IE outside loop]. Sorry, for confusion.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LaadAllePaginaenScrape()

  Dim URL As String
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim botao As Object
  Dim htmlEle As Object
  Dim e As Long

  e = 1
  URL = "Somepage"

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate URL
  Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

  Do
    For Each htmlEle In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
      With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
        .Range("B" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
        .Range("C" & e).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
      End With
      e = e + 1
    Next htmlEle

    Set botao = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary center-block ng-binding")(0)
    botao.Click (1)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
  Loop Until botao.hasAttribute("disabled")

  ie.Quit
  Set ie = Nothing
  Set botao = Nothing
  Set htmlEle = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested this one, and this did exactly what I was looking for! Thankyou for the effort!